# How to convert the momentJs time to local time

Tags: node.js, mongoose, momentjs

I am trying to save the localtime as default when creating an item in mongoose

```
const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  item_name: { type: String, required: true },
  shop_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Shop" },
  createTime: { type: Date, default: moment().utcOffset(7) },
});
```

As you can see I am trying to offset the `moment` utc time but it is not working? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you use just moment() without utcOffset, can not get local time? because this function returns the real offset from UTC and usually use new Date() to local time

Answer (score 1):

You're just passing the moment instance to your `createTime` field and that won't work. After you use `.utcOffset()` to convert the date to your local time zone, you need to extract it as something that can be understood by mongoose as a date. According to the [momentjs doccumentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/), the fix should be as easy as adding .format() yo your moment object: `moment().utcOffset(7).format()`.

Answer (score 0):

moment() dose not return a new Date()
mongoose schema expects a Date instance
Try:

```
const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  item_name: { type: String, required: true },
  shop_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Shop" },
  createTime: { type: Date, default: new Date(moment().utcOffset(7).format()) },
});
```